# Bind self created JSON array with different key names to sap.m.List

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I create the following JSON Array:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  ItemSet: [
    { "item1": this.oTextBundle.getText("Flower") },
    { "item2": this.oTextBundle.getText("Tree") }
  ]
});
//then I push that model to my dialog
this._oDialog.setModel(oModel);
```

then I have a list in my dialog which looks like this:

```
<List id="idList" width="700px" items="{ path:'/ItemSet'}">
  <CustomListItem>
    <Label id="id1" text="{item1}" width="350px" />
  </CustomListItem>
  <CustomListItem>
    <Label id="id2" text="{item2}" width="350px" />
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

In the end the only value that is bound is from the item2 the i18n translation for "Tree" is loaded into my list, "Flower" does not appear. When I switch to the following coding:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  ItemSet: [{
      "item": this.oTextBundle.getText("Flower")
    },
    {
      "item": this.oTextBundle.getText("Tree")
    }
  ]
});
//then I push that model to my dialog
this._oDialog.setModel(oModel);
```

```html
<List id="idList" width="700px" items="{ path:'/ItemSet'}">
  <CustomListItem>
    <Label id="id1" text="{item}" width="350px" />
  </CustomListItem>
  <CustomListItem>
    <Label id="id2" text="{item}" width="350px" />
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

so the key name in all JSON objects has to be the same? Or is there a way to implement it the way I want with different keys in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use different keys in your model, you can have a key for **`ID`** and another for the **`values`**.

An example:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  ItemSet: [
    { "value": this.oTextBundle.getText("Flower"), "id": "1" },
    { "value": this.oTextBundle.getText("Tree"), "id": "2" }
  ]
}); 
this._oDialog.setModel(oModel);
```

This way you still have a key identifier for each entry and you can easily bind the model to your [`sap.m.List`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.List):

```
<List mode="SingleSelectMaster" items="{ path:'/ItemSet'}" selectionChange="listPress">
  <CustomListItem>
    <Label text="{value}"/>
  </CustomListItem> 
</List>
```

You will then be able to get the **`ID`** for the selected item with this method:

```
listPress: function (oControlEvent) {
   var oCtx = oControlEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();
   var oPressedItem = this.getView().getModel().getProperty(oCtx.getPath());
}
```

`oPressedItem.id` will give you the **`ID`** for the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing a template for your list binding, you are providing the two items you wish for. Sapui5 expect template to be one and only control, when several are provided it only takes the latest.
In your case you end up with item2, simply because the second object in your template refers to item2.

As suggested above, change your view to :

```
<List id="idList" width="700px" items="{/ItemSet}">
  <CustomListItem>
    <Label text="{item}" width="350px" />
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

And it will work

edit: the implicit aggregation for List is 'items'. This means that the code above is strictly equivalent to

```
<List id="idList" width="700px" items="{/ItemSet}">
  <items>
    <CustomListItem>
      <Label text="{item}" width="350px" />
    </CustomListItem>
  </items>
</List>
```

And since you binded the 'items' aggregation, sapui5 will consider anything inside the 'items' tag to be the template